# Does Java have a Converter?

Tags: java

I'm looking for an `interface` which accepts a generic `Object` of one type, and returns another. In effect, it performs a kind of *conversion* or *interpretation* of the supplied value.

I could easily create a class, as follows:

```
public interface IConverter<T, U> {
    /** Converts the @param pT to one of type U. */
    U convert(final T pT);
}
```

However, I don't want to re-invent the wheel!

Is there an existing class in Java 7 that I should be using instead?

**Edit**

I should emphasise that the conversion to be performed is totally context-specific, and it doesn't have to really *care* about the underlying data within the class; it can be totally arbitrary.

Imagine the use case where I'd like to provide a user-friendly description of an `Object`. Here, I'd like to provide translation between an `Object` instance and a `String`, *without* overriding `toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 introduces Lambda expressions and implements them through anonymous instances of `java.util.function.Function<R, T>` providing the method `R apply(T t)`.

Comment: Thanks, that would have been perfect, but I'm using Java 7! I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

There might be more method to do this , but as per my practice I use ObjectMapper to convert one object to another.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
//then declear the ObjectMapper variable
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
//In your method where you want to convert object just write below code.
mapper.convertValue(T, U.class);
```

Hope this will solve your use case.

Comment: Hi Nishant, my current application uses Jackson, so this actually looks very promising. However, I'm curious... What if the classes possess no relationship to one-another? Do the member variables in each `class` need to own matching `@JsonProperty`s?

Comment: Hi @AlexT. If classes possess no relationship to one-another then class needs there own mapping , As ObjectMapper works on reflection you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162916/how-does-the-jackson-mapper-know-what-field-in-each-json-object-to-assign-to-a-c for better answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many converters for most common formats:

- From String (in json format) to bean
- From String (in xml format) to bean
- From Map to bean
- From bean to Map
- From array to List
- From List to array
- From String to Date

Comment: Thanks Davide, but I'm looking for a class which uses generic type qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're limited by Java 7, you can include [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) which provides similar [Functional interface semantics](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained) as in Java 8.