# How are JSON values generated for requests in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

In the Entity class, If I have a function starting with get< something >() which returns a constant value, it is included in the JSON response even though no such member variable is declared. `Static` functions do not appear in the generated json.

I don't know what to search for.

I want to know why this is so and what the underlying mechanism for this is.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Entity
public class AssignedBook {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
  private Integer id;
  @OneToOne
  private Book book;
  @OneToOne
  private Users user;

  public static Integer getSomeId() {
    return 8;
  }
  public Integer someAwesomeId() {
    return 8;
  }
}
```

My code for the `repository` is

```
@Query(value="select new AssignedBook(id, book) from AssignedBook ab where ab.user.id=:userId")
  public List<AssignedBook> findByIdAndBookId(Integer userId);
```

For `id=15` and some `book` value this will return the json

```
[
    {
        "id": 15,
        "book": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Rage of Angels",
            "author": "Sidney Sheldon"
        },
        "someAwesomeId": 8
    }
]
```

Comment: Spring Boot uses Jackson by default, and since there is a value, albeit constant, it will be serialized as such. If you don't want that field to be part of introspection-based serialization and deserialization, just "mark" it with `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: That's just normal, either use `@JsonIgnore` like @x80486 suggested or use Data Transfer Objects (DTO) for transferring only the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [x80486](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4695271/x80486) for the direction.

`Spring boot` uses `Jackson` which uses reflection to match `getXXX` and maps it.

Better explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162916/how-does-the-jackson-mapper-know-what-field-in-each-json-object-to-assign-to-a-c)